# Flutter App Not Uploading To Appstore Connect

Tags: flutter, dart, app-store, app-store-connect

I'm trying to install apps on my apple store connect account but it always fails

I have repeatedly checked for the existence of my account, but there is still time for my account to expire.
Please Help Me I Need To Finish This Job Today

Answer (score 1):

I understand App Store Connect's Privacy Policies etc in June. Registered Account Creator Must Accept Keys Once Accepted It Will Work.